# Laravel Unknown column '_token' in 'field list'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3, csrf

I've noticed strange behaviour over some `Laravel` apps.

When I run lets say

```
Users::where("id",$request->input("id"))->update($request->input());
```

Sometimes it goes through fine. In other cases I get

```
 Unknown column '_token' in 'field list'
```

So sometimes it only reads what is set in the `$fillable` parameter, and other times it takes everything from `$request->input()`. I keep comparing different models and see no difference. I know I can work around it by using the `$request->only([])` method, but does anybody else have or had this issue and perhaps know a reason behind it?

**Edit**

This is my model.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BookingRequests extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = array(
        "account_id",
        "quote_id",
        "booking_id",
        "website_id",
        "color",
        "custom_group_name",
        "is_confirmed",
        "ready_to_issue",
        "created_by",
    );


    /**
     * Return Quote
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function Quote(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Quotes',"quote_id","id");
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
/**
     * Update Booking Reques
     * @param Request $request
     */
    public function update(Request $request){
        /**
         * Validate
         */
        $this->validate($request,array(
            "id" => "required"
        ));
        /**
         * Update
         */
        BookingRequests::where("id",$request->input("id"))->update($request->input());
        /**
         * Return
         */
        return redirect()->back()->with("success","Booking updated");
    }
```

This is being run on `Laravel 5.3.31`

Comment: How are you debugging this? At least log request data so you know what you got from there. There are probably hundreds of thousands of laravel deploys out there using `Model->update`, I'd be _really_ surprised if you were the first to find a bug that is causing what you are describing. More likely you are using it wrong. Please show us a way to reproduce this and tell us how you are debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest what you are doing now is really risky. In fact it's possible now to update any fields no matter of `$fillable` property. This is because you are now updating like this:

```
Users::where("id",$request->input("id"))->update($request->input());
```

When you are making update like this in fact you are making update directly in database and Eloquent things are not used so the query that is executed looks something like this:

```
UPDATE users SET a=1, b=2 WHERE id = 5
```

so if anyone sends existing columns in this table they will be updated what is very very risky because you don't want anyone to modify columns you don't want to.

But if you do something like this:

```
$user = Users::where("id",$request->input("id"))->firstOrFail();
$user->update($request->input());
```

In above case Eloquent is used (first you find record in database and it's Eloquent model and then you try to update this Eloquent model), so now it's possible to update only fields that are in `$fillable` (assuming you are using 'fillable-way' but you do looking at your model). So now, no matter what is send in request, only fields in `$fillable` will be updated.

Obviously above could be written in a bit shorter way:

```
$user = Users::findOrFail($request->input("id"));
$user->update($request->all());
```

or even in one like like this:

```
Users::findOrFail($request->input("id"))->update($request->all());
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$request->except('_token');` By the way, check twice, that all data what could come by request is expected.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this, but i want to know why sometimes this error happens and other times it does not

Answer (score 0):

It not `sometimes this error happens`, `$fillable` only works with mass assignment with creation/insertion not in updation, so when you update it include column `_token`.

Comment: fillable has to do with `update` as well (as update is `fill` and `save`) but when called on am existing model instance not the builder.